# Guava LoadingCache loads new value everytime for same key

Tags: java, caching, guava

I'm using the Guava LoadingCache to store results from database queries. However, despite not setting an eviction policy, doing a get on the cache through getFromCache() results in my debug point in the CacheLoader load() method being hit every time, therefore also resulting a debug point in the database query method getKeyFromDatabase() being hit every time.

Here is my code:

```
private final LoadingCache<String, QueryResult> cache;

public MyDao() {
    cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .maximumSize(40)
        .build(new CacheLoader<String, QueryResult>() {
            @Override
            public QueryResult load(String key) throws DatabaseException {
                return getKeyFromDatabase(key);
            }
        });
}

public QueryResult getFromCache(String key) throws DatabaseException {
    try {
        return cache.get(key);
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        throw new DatabaseException(e);
    }
}

private QueryResult getKeyFromDatabase(String key) throws DatabaseException {
    try {
        ...
        return new QueryResult();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new DatabaseException(e);
    }
}
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: That code doesn't compile, does it? (`.getFromCache()`)

Comment: Also, please specify a more specific exception than `Exception` in your `CacheLoader`; when you implement a method which throws something, you can change the exception thrown to any subclass of the given exception.

Comment: Yeah, I'm curious about the exception handling... if `getKeyFromDatabase` throws an exception every time and that fact is being hidden from you somehow, it's going to have to keep trying to load again every time.

Comment: I edited my post, adding exceptions. I stepped through getKeyFromDatabase() and load() and getFromCache(), there is no exception thrown, it is just loading from the database everytime.

Comment: I also tried setting an .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES) in the builder and it still was hitting the load method everytime for the same key.

Comment: I tried evaluating cache.asMap() in subsequent getFromCache() calls on the same key and it's always empty before load() is called...

Comment: @ddxue Whatever you set, you can only *cause* eviction. `CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build(...)` creates a never evicting cache, setting `maximumSize`, `expire..`, or whatever adds eviction reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Alright false alarm guys, guava is not actually broken (surprise surprise). The reason is cause the code that was instantiating the DAO was instantiating a new object every time, so a new cache was also instantiated every time. I made the cache a static variable and it now works.